# In Aliens, what would happen to the dead bodies?

Tags: alien-franchise

In Aliens, what would happen to the dead bodies? The Aliens clearly would kill many humans, but it's not clear what would be done to them afterward. Were they eaten or only parts eaten?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a deleted scene, organic matter is used to grow an egg, a process called [eggmorphing](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Eggmorphing).

It appears that in Aliens, the still living colonists were used for nutrients or as hosts for the hive.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on the process?

Comment: @Valorum the process is unknown

Answer (score 6):

It isn't clear from the movies what they do with them. It is clear that aliens need to eat. [This question covers that](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6282/in-the-aliens-movie-what-do-the-aliens-eat)

They do need to consume something to grow from chest bursters to full grown aliens.

If you go with the idea that they eat organic food, it's pretty safe to say they eat dead humans that aren't suitable for impregnation.

Another way to explain their growth is that they eat inorganic materials like plastic and metal. Ash researched in Alien:

> ... several interesting characteristics, including the Xenomorph's ability to replace its cells with polarized silicon, giving it a prolonged resistance to adverse environmental conditions

If they don't eat their victims it's pretty safe to assume they drag them away and hide them, as (especially in Alien 3) all you find are blood splatters.

> Near the end of Alien 3 where Dylan is stopping the Alient from running out of the lead mould it does seem like the Alien is eating him. If not eating it's playing with it's food like a cat taking bites from a mouse

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. In the original AvP game, the Chestburster level ends when you find a cat in a pet carrier. You apparently eat the cat and start the next level as an adolescent Alien right after your transformation. You later molt from adolescent to adult Alien after attacking a solitary human (presumably eating him as well).